# Function in one line to count winning coupons on lottery

Tags: python, list, statistics, counter

I have coupons for Lotto (lottery):

```
coupons = [[1,4,7,34,45,67], [2,8,16,34,35,38] ... ]
```

and result:

```
result = [7,12,13,26,29,34]
```

How can I count my winning numers on coupons **IN ONE LINE** ?
I would like return statistics, for example like this:

```
statistics = [20, 15, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

where

statistics[0] - amount of coupons with 0 winning numbers,

statistics[1] - amount of coupons with 1 winning numbers,

statistics[2] - amount of coupons with 2 winning numbers,

statistics[3] - amount of coupons with 3 winning numbers,

statistics[4] - amount of coupons with 4 winning numbers,

statistics[5] - amount of coupons with 5 winning numbers,

statistics[6] - amount of coupons with 6 winning numbers

Comment: Initialise the statistics array to 0, loop through each coupon comparing digits, increment applicable statistic.

Comment: Why is "in one line" so important that you need to both capitalize it and put it in bold?  Would an import line be a problem?

Comment: Your data doesn't match the results. For one thing, you don't have 20 coupons, so `statistics[0]` can't be 20 in your expected output

Comment: how about this (super inefficient) approach: map(lambda x:sum([(n in result) for n in x]), coupons).count(i) for i in range(1,len(result)+1)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

coupons = [[1,4,7,34,45,67]  , [2,8,16,34,35,38],
           [7,12,13,26,29,34], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
result  = [7,12,13,26,29,34]

answer = Counter([6-len(set(result)-set(s)) for s in coupons])
```

The last line is the one-liner requested. Notice that I had to change the data structures used internally for this to work - both the coupons and the result are represented in terms of *sets* now, and the result is stored in a `Counter` (a special kind of dictionary), but the answer for all practical purposes behaves as an array:

```
answer[0]
> 1

...

answer[6]
> 1
```

**UPDATE**

OK, I managed to squeeze the conversion to an actual list in a single line. It's *not* efficient (you're better off using my first solution above) but heck, it works and it's in a single line:

```
[Counter([6-len(set(result)-set(s)) for s in coupons])[x] for x in xrange(7)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't count importing as "a line", then this would produce your results in a single line:

```
>>> coupons = [[1,4,7,34,45,67], [2,8,16,34,35,38], [1,4,7,13,55],
               [7,12,13,26,29,19]]
>>> result = [7,12,13,26,29,34]
>>>
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(len(set(c).intersection(set(result))) for c in coupons)
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 5: 1})
```

Comment: whoops, forgot to remove the list comp from when i was testing

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the job:

```
from collections import *
cnt = defaultdict(int, Counter(len(set(result) & set(c)) for c in coupons))
statistics = [cnt[n] for n in range(7)]
```

This can be trivially combined into a one-liner by separating the three statements with semicolons, although I fail to see what this would achieve other than making the code harder to read.

If `statistics` doesn't have to be a list, you can drop the call to `defaultdict()` as well as the last line, and use the `Counter` instance directly.

Answer (score 0):

First write a function that returns the appropriate box, given a lotto ticket and the winning numbers, i.e. your example of

```
ticket = [1,4,7,34,45,67]
result = [7,12,13,26,29,34]
```

would return 2.

Then, write a function that iterates through your entire array of tickets, incrementing the appropriate array index based on the return value of your first function.

Edit: oh, one line of code, or one line of array?

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy it is easy (but a bit ugly):

```
coupon=np.random.randint(0,100,(50,6)) % 50 coupons with 6 numbers between 0-99
statistics=np.random.randint(0,100,(6,))

np.histogram(np.sum((coupon==statistics[0]) | (coupon==statistics[1]) | (coupon==statistics[2]) | (coupon==statistics[3]) | (coupon==statistics[4]) | (coupon==statistics[5]),1),bins=np.arange(0,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coupons = [[1,4,7,34,45,67], [2,8,16,34,35,38] … ]
result = [7,12,13,26,29,34]
```

If the positions of the numbers in `coupons`/`result` doesn't matter (`coupon` has 4 winning numbers, even if they are in different positions than in `result`), then this would work (it would work even better if there are no duplicate numbers and you don't have to match against the occurrence frequency of such duplicate numbers):

```
result = set(result)
statistics = [len([coupon for coupon in coupons if len(set(coupon).intersection(result))==i]) for i in range(len(result))]
```

However, this is highly inefficient (O(n^2)). I would suggest a dictionary based approach and sorting:

```
def getStats:
    result = set(result)
    statistics = [0]*len(result)
    for coupon in coupons:
        statistics[len(set(coupon).intersection(result))] += 1
    return statistics
```